# When sessiom timeout expires, send status to Database. ASP.Net and Jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp.net

I have the following session timeout jquery statement:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         idleTime = 0;

         $(document).ready(function () {

             // Inkrementerer every minute
             var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 minute


             // reset the counter when mouse moved or key pressed  
             $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                 idleTime = 0;
             });
             $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                 idleTime = 0;
             });
         });

         function timerIncrement() {

             document.getElementById("<%= lblSessionTime.ClientID %>").innerText =         idleTime;
             idleTime = idleTime + 1;
             if (idleTime > 19) { // 20 minutes

                 // Send status to Database

             }

         }

</script>
```

When the idle time exceed the 20 minutes i want to send a status to MySQL database, that the page is now Offline. I cannot figure it out how to do it with JQuery. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2:**

All aspx code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Drivhus 1.aspx.cs" Inherits="FS07.Drivhus_1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             idleTime = 0;

             $(document).ready(function () {

                 // Inkrementerer inaktiv tilstand counteren hvert minut.
                 var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 minute


                 // Nulstiller counteren når musen er bevæget eller der bliver tastet.  
                 $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                     idleTime = 0;
                 });
                 $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                     idleTime = 0;
                 });
             });

             function timerIncrement() {

                 document.getElementById("<%= lblSessionTime.ClientID %>").innerText = idleTime;
                 idleTime = idleTime + 1;
                 if (idleTime > 19) { // 20 minutes

                     // Send status to Database
                     PageMethods.SendStatustoDB();
                     alert("Connected");
                 }

             }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>     
    <div>
     <h6>Session time left:&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblSessionTime"  runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;minutes.</h6>
     <h2>Her vises SCADA GUI</h2>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use ajax to call a web service which updates your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you call a C# WebMethod? This is going to be an AJAX approach and will require the use of ScriptManager..

**ASPX:** Make sure to add a ScriptManager object inside your **FORM** tag and set `EnablePageMethods = true`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    /* REST OF YOUR HTML */

</form>
```

**JavaScript:** You will need to modify your *timerIncrement* function and call a *C# WebMethod*

```
function timerIncrement() {
    document.getElementById("<%= lblSessionTime.ClientID %>").innerText = idleTime;
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;

    if (idleTime > 19) { // 20 minutes

        // Call C# WebMethod to send status to Database
        PageMethods.SendStatustoDB();
    }
}
```

**C# Code-Behind:** You need to reference the following:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

Then add the following method and make sure you put `[WebMethod]` before method declaration:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendStatustoDB()
{
    // code to connect to DB and set status!
}
```

Comment: You assume the OP is using `ScriptManager`.

Comment: @Rick S, thats correct..@user3346509: There are a few things you must do to set this up. Let me update my answer, can you post your ASPX code?

Comment: Answer also updated. Let me know if you run into issues, good luck!

Comment: @lucidgold i did try it out, but when i run it, the session timer will not run anymore, it's freezing. sometimes it gets 1 or 2 but then reset to zero again. When i remove the ASP scriptmanager it works again. Check Update 2

Comment: I am not sure what is happening, its working perfectly for me? I copied and pasted your code exactly and put a debug point on SendStatustoDB() method and its hitting correctly? Maybe you have something else happening in your C# code-behind. Can you post it?

Comment: It worked now :) my SendStatustoDB() method was after page_load. When i moved it before page_load it worked. I dont know what the problem was but its working :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be very easy.  This code will works in the same domain as the url provided in the ajax call:

in your client:

```
<script>
  function notifySessionExpired(somedata){
      var url = "some-script-in-your-server.php";
      $.ajax({
          url: url, type: 'post',  data: { args: somedata , info: 'notifyexpire' } ,
          success: function(result){
             $('#log').html("result was: "+result);
          },
          error: function(e){
              $('#log').html(e.responseText);
          }
      });
  }
</script>
```

in your server (some-script-in-your-sever.php)

```
--begin-of-file--
if(isset($_POST["info"])){
   if("notifysession" == $_POST["info"]){
      $args = $_POST["args"];
      echo fireYourServerSideEventAndDoSomething($args);
   }
}
--end-of-file--
```

Comment: can be PHP, ASP, JSP etc...this must not be a problem at all.